# Get data based on two dates values filtered by month

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have list of events, each event has two dates; start date and end date. I want to create a filter by months. How do I return dates that ranges between a month that a user selects? 
for example, lets say the user selects month October, I want to return all events that are within this month.

I have used this to get the dates that ranges between todays date but now stuck on  how to get the range between a month.

```
DateTime dateToCheck = DateTime.Today.Date;
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Parse(item["Start Time"].ToString());
DateTime endDate = DateTime.Parse(item["End Time"].ToString());
foreach (SPListItem item in collection)
{
    if (startDate <= dateToCheck && dateToCheck < endDate)
    {
         ListBox1.Items.Add(item["EventTitle"].ToString());
    } 
}
```

Comment: Please add more info did you tried something?Its difficult to formulate the answer from Text only.

Answer (score 3):

```
// set up dummy data
var dates = new[] {DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now};
int month = GetMonth();
// get result
var result = dates.Where(date => date.Month == month);
```

EDIT: if you need to make sure the dates have the correct year as well, use

```
var dates = new[] {DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now};
int year = GetYear();
int month = GetMonth();
var result = dates.Where(date => date.Year == year && date.Month == month);
```

Of course, you can get the year/month numbers as well as the date-list from wherever.

EDIT2: if you get a DateTime object as input modify accordingly:

```
var dates = new[] {DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now};
var input = GetDateTime();
var result = dates.Where(date => date.Year == input.Year && date.Month == input.Month);
```

Answer (score 0):

You still can use your code with little modifications. As start date you have to select 00:00 time of 1st of the month and as end date you have to use 00:00 time of 1st of the next month. In case of October 2015 it would be: `1 Oct 2015 <= date < 1 Nov 2015`.

```
int year = 2015;
int month = 10;
DateTime dateToCheck = DateTime.Today.Date;
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
DateTime endDate = startDate.AddMonths(1);
foreach (SPListItem item in collection)
{
    if (startDate <= dateToCheck && dateToCheck < endDate)
    {
         ListBox1.Items.Add(item["EventTitle"].ToString());
    } 
}
```